# FEA meshing of irregular geometry

Tags: finite-element-method, geometry, meshing

I work on the simulation of sand particles and usually use tetrahedral free-meshing to represent their complex geometries for finite element analysis. I have recently spent some time looking into methods that may be superior to this simplistic approach. Two methods, IGA and the “sculpt” algorithm in Coreform Cubit, seem promising. As I have very little background in meshing, I thought I’d turn to this site to see if anyone has advice they could offer on how to best create meshes for such irregular geometries. For reference, I have included an example sand particle geometry that has been free-meshed using tetrahedral elements below. Preferably, I would not defeature the details of the particle surface too much.

[image]

Comment: Meshing for FEA depends on geometry, loading, and the output from the analysis that you care about.  Given a geometry dependent mesh, one could come up with a loading or desired result that would require the mesh to be refined.